# Converting an integer column to a character in mySQL

Tags: mysql

My users table currently has a field `sex` which is either 1 or 2.  I want to convert those values to "F" or "M" and put them into a different column.  Is there any way to do this in mySQL?

I can write Ruby code to do this in the console, but I have on the order of 100K users and don't want to stall production while I loop.

Comment: you can use `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Do you mean you want to add an extra column to the table or do you just want to get F/M when you query the existing table.

Comment: I have a new column that should contain F/M while the original column contains 1/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query:**

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET sex = (CASE WHEN sex = 1 THEN 'M' WHEN sex = 2 THEN 'F' ELSE '' END);
```

Add extra column with name `gender` then:

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET gender = (CASE WHEN sex = 1 THEN 'M' WHEN sex = 2 THEN 'F' ELSE '' END);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 3 steps

**step 1**
Add a new column into the table

`alter table table_name add column sex_n char(1)`;

**step 2**
Write an update query

```
update table_name
set sex_n = case when sex = 1 then 'M' else 'F' end ;
```

**step 3**
Verify if the data is populated correctly then do

```
alter table table_name drop column sex
alter table table_name change sex_n sex char(1);
```

If you do not want an extra column you can use select to convert as

```
select
case when sex=1 then 'M'
else 'F'
end as sex 
from table_name
```

Comment: Does the latter work if the `sex` column is type integer?

Comment: The last one is if you do not want to add another column into the table and using select you can modify and display, but the column will still contain `1 or 2` but while display via query it will show `M or F`